# How can I make a pure assembly project in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

How can I make a masm project in Visual Studio? I remember doing this in class a while back, but I've since forgotten, and Google is only getting me inline assembly.

Comment: It can be still done in the latest versions of VS. I wrote up a list of instructions on how to do it about 5 years ago, unfortunately the place i posted those instructions has long since disappeared. You may find it archived somewhere if you search for the combinations of terms *vs2003 instructions project sluggy asm*.

Comment: Tried it with VS 2008 and it works fine. :) Very Helpfull question because google realls turns up only C/C++ intefacing.

Comment: [Assembly programming - WinAsm vs Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52796300) has a walk-through with images for that version.  IDK if it's still accurate for later versions.  vs. [external assembly file in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33751509) is about adding an asm source file to a project with some C or C++ files

Comment: For use with Irvine32, see http://asmirvine.com/gettingStartedVS2022/index.htm#tutorial32

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Start with the Win32 Console mode project template.  Delete the .cpp files.  Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer window, Custom Build Rules, check Microsoft Macro Assembler.  In VS2015 use Build Dependencies, Build Customizations, check masm.

Add a new .asm file by right-clicking the Source Files node, Add, Code, C++ File, be sure to use the .asm extension.  In the property window change the File Type to C/C++ Code so it gets passed to the linker.

Linker settings, Manifest file, Generate = No.  With these settings I could build and debug this sample .asm file:

```
.486
.MODEL FLAT
.CODE
START:
   ret
END START
```

Comment: I tried this with Visual Studio 2008 and it also works. To add a new ASM file, create an empty file `myfile.asm` in your source directory, and then import it by using `Add -> Existing Item ...`. VS will recognize the `asm` extension and creates an appropriate build entry for you, so you can easily assemble and link it.

Comment: 13 upvotes, we should create a visual studio project template

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in "modern" Visual Studio builds. Here are instructions for a very old one: http://jimweller.com/jim-weller/jim/vc98asmqs/vc98asmqs-4.html

**Edit:** Looks like you're right--it shipped with VS 2005. Since then, Microsoft has started to [distribute MASM for free](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2006/06/08/622485.aspx), and have probably discontinued support for it. :(

Comment: I remember doing it in Visual Studio 2005

Comment: In modern visual studio :
Open visual studio 2010 as administrator
New project --> win32 console application
Click on next
Uncheck "Precompiled header"
Check "Empty project"
Click finish
Right click the project in solution explorer
Choose "Build customizations"
Check "masmm(.targets, .props)
Click OK
Right click again the project in solution explorer
Choose "Properties"
On "Configurations:" choose "All Configurations"
Unfold "Configuration Properties"
Unfold "Linker"
Click on "Manifest File"
Put "Generate Manifest" to "No (/MANIFEST:NO)"
Click "Apply"
Click "OK"