# external assembly file in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, x86-64, masm

I searched and found I can not use `__asm` in x64 in visual studio. Instead I have to use an external assembly file.

How can I add external assembly file to my win32 console project?

How can compile them?

Can you explain step by step.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**How to build a mixed-source x64-project with a x64 assembly file in Visual Studio**:

1) Start Visual Studio (Community) 2015 and choose `FILE - New - Project`.

[image: Screenshot]

2) In the next window choose `Win 32 Console Application`.

[image: Screenshot]

3) You get a confirmation. Click on `Next >`.

[image: Screenshot]

4) In the next window you can accept the default settings. Click on `Finish`.

[image: Screenshot]

5) Make sure, that the project is highlighted in the Solution Explorer and and choose `PROJECT - Build Customizations...` from the menu.

[image: Screenshot]

6) In the next window tick `masm(.targets,.props)` and click on `OK`.

[image: Screenshot]

7) Choose `Build - Configuration Manager...`

[image: Screenshot]

8) Change the `Active solution platform` to x64

[image: Screenshot]

9) Create callee.asm: `PROJECT - Add New Item`.

[image: Screenshot]

10) In the next window choose `C++File(.cpp)` and - **IMPORTANT!** - give it a name with an `.asm` extension. Click on `Add`.

[image: Screenshot]

10) Now check if the `.asm` file has the right properties. In the Solution Explorer right-click on the file and choose `Properties`.

[image: Screenshot]

11) In the Property Page you should see at least:

```
Excluded From Build    (empty) or No
Item Type              Microsoft Macro Assembler
```

[image: Screenshot]

Under `Command Line` ensure that `ml64.exe` is chosen as the assembler.

[image: Screenshot]

Click on `OK`.

12) Now you can fill the files with content.

**ConsoleApplication1.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" void hello_from_asm();

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello from CPP" << endl;
    hello_from_asm();
    return 0;
}
```

**callee.asm:**

```
PUBLIC hello_from_asm
EXTERN puts:PROC

.data

    hello1 db "Hello from ASM.",0

.code

hello_from_asm PROC
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 32                 ; Shadow Space
    and spl, -16                ; Align stack at 16

    lea rcx, hello1
    call puts

    leave                       ; Restore stack (rsp) & frame pointer (rbp)
    ret
hello_from_asm ENDP

END
```

13) Build the .exe

[image: Screenshot]

and run it with <kbd>CTRL-F5</kbd>.

The application will be opened in a new window.

Comment: Related: [Assembly programming - WinAsm vs Visual Studio 2017](//stackoverflow.com/q/52796300) for pure asm projects.  (I've added this and the other link to [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info))

Comment: Works fine on VS 2015. However, VS 2017 shows message: A1000, cannot open file: x.asm.

Comment: Some gotchas: Build Customisation only shows up in the Project menu when the project itself (second entry) is selected in the Solution Explorer window, not any of the source files or so. You might also run into [SAFESEH errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14710577/2171120); try to not disable it in the linker but _en_able it in the MASM properties instead.