# How to use NtCurrentTeb() without Windows header files?

Tags: c, winapi, assembly

Windows stores the [TEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) in FS (32bit) or GS (64bit) segment register. In a program using `NtCurrentPeb()` the x86 instruction is `mov rax, gs:60h`. The `0x60` value is `offsetof(TEB, ProcessEnvironmentBlock)`.

To use this in a program I've to include both `Windows.h` and `Winternl.h` header file which has bunch of other `#define`. As the question said I want to use the function without these header file and by directly accessing the segment register. I've also made a separate header file with the TEB and PEB structure. So how can I do that? I was thinking with `__asm` keyword and a `typedef NtCurrentTeb()` or something.

Comment: you want programming for windows without windows header files ? wwhy you not want include `windows.h` ? you of course can use `__readfsdword` and `__readgsqword`, etc. but what sense in all this ?

Comment: `__asm` is not supported in 64 bit builds

Comment: `__readfsdword` not macro but inline function for *cl* compiler. how not use windows headers or `__readfsdword` help you *to deep dive in API and ABI.* ?

Comment: You have this marked as both 'assembly' and 'c.'  Does that mean you are coding in assembler?  Using VStudio?  Gcc?  Using hardware specific features (like `gs:` or `fs:`) isn't going to have a generic solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from `gs` or `fs` segment register, I have used this assembly in Visual Studio. Create a C/C++ empty project in Visual Studio with [these settings enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757749/8928481). `fs` or `gs` segment register provides [NT_TIB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block) structure in 32 bit and 64 bit Windows respectively. TEB is at `0x30` offset in NT_TIB structure. So the assembly in 64 bit will be: `mov rax, gs:[30h]`.

Here is a sample source code to get current directory of an executable file:

- ProcParam.asm:

```
.code

ProcParam PROC

mov rax, gs:[30h]      ; TEB from gs in 64 bit only
mov rax, [rax+60h]     ; PEB
mov rax, [rax+20h]     ; RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS
ret

ProcParam ENDP

end
```

- main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct _UNICODE_STRING {
    unsigned short Length;
    unsigned short MaximumLength;
    wchar_t* Buffer;
} UNICODE_STRING, *PUNICODE_STRING;

typedef struct _CURDIR {
    UNICODE_STRING DosPath;
    void* Handle;
} CURDIR, *PCURDIR;

/*Extracted from ntdll.pdb file*/

typedef struct _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS {
    unsigned int MaximumLength;
    unsigned int Length;
    unsigned int Flags;
    unsigned int DebugFlags;
    void* ConsoleHandle;
    unsigned int ConsoleFlags;
    void* StandardInput;
    void* StandardOutput;
    void* StandardError;
    CURDIR CurrentDirectory;
    /*Many more*/
} RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS, *PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS;

PRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcParam(void);

int main(void)
{
    wprintf(L"%s\n", ProcParam()->CurrentDirectory.DosPath.Buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I really do not understand why you answered your own question incompletely. This confuses further readers because you did not provide the appropriate answer to **the question itself**.

You do not need to use ASM for this, you can use [intrinsic functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/compiler-intrinsics?view=vs-2019) like so:

```
#ifdef _M_X64
    auto pPEB = (PPEB)__readgsqword(0x60);
#elif _M_IX86
    auto pPEB = (PPEB)__readfsdword(0x30);
#else
    #error "PPEB Architecture Unsupported"
#endif
```

But to answer **the actual question**, here is how to do is via ASM:

**x64 ASM (TEB/PEB):**

```
GetTEBAsm64 proc
    mov rax, qword ptr gs:[00000030h]
    ret
GetTEBAsm64 endp

GetPEBAsm64 proc
    mov rax, qword ptr gs:[00000060h]
    ret
GetPEBAsm64 endp
```

**x86 - PEB:**

```
__asm
    {
    mov eax, dword ptr fs : [00000030h]
    mov peb, eax
}
```

**x86 - TEB:**

```
__asm
    {
        mov eax, dword ptr fs : [00000018h]
        mov teb, eax
    }
```

I strongly hope that my answer is clear and that someone else in the future can benefit from it.

Comment: Why not make `GetTEBAsm64` look like `mov rax, qword ptr gs:[00000030h]` `ret` . A lot of unnecessary code. Same for `GetPEBAsm64`

Comment: @MichaelPetch Well... I don't even like using ASM in projects. I find intrinsic nicer. But the OP needed a solution so... :)

Comment: I agree about the intrinsics and it is the best way to do it. I was just curious about the bloat in the asm. No problem. I only came across your answer as the code was referenced in another question today.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I see, well, it's good that I`m popular LOL.

Answer (score 1):

Declare function prototype and link against ntdll.dll.

Comment: for what need link against ntdll.dll ? `NtCurrentTeb()` not require this. if implement `NtCurrentPeb()` by read `ProcessEnvironmentBlock` value from teb - again - for what `ntdll.dll` here if we nothing call from it ?

Comment: @RbMm `NtCurrentTeb` is not only an inline function from the Windows headers, but it also exists as a public function with the same name in `ntdll.dll` (but only in the 32 bit version of the DLL).

Comment: @dialer really exist in 32bit version of the DLL (but not in 64). not view any sense use this import, when exist macro and for both 32/64

Comment: @RbMm The public symbol allows interop from other programming languages and technologies which cannot access `fs` and `gs` directly. But the fact that it doesn't exist in 64bit is very limiting, of course.