# PEB X86 wrong address

Tags: assembly, winapi, low-level, low-level-code

So here is my question :

I wanted to get PEB from x64 and x86 without calling NtQueryProcessInformation.

I use ASM from this question : [How to use NtCurrentTeb() without Windows header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52616221/how-to-use-ntcurrentteb-without-windows-header-files)

ASM Code for X64 :

```
            byte[] asm = new byte[] { 0x53, 0x48, 0x31, 0xDB, 0x48, 0x31, 0xC0, 0x65, 0x48, 0x8B, 0x1C, 0x25, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0x89, 0xD8, 0x5B, 0xC3 };
        /* 
        push rbx
        xor rbx,rbx
        xor rax,rax
        mov rbx, qword ptr gs:[0x00000060]
        mov rax, rbx
        pop rbx
        ret
        */
```

And for X86 (I wrote same function based on question and x64 code):

```
 byte[] asm32 = new byte[] { 0x53, 0x31, 0xDB, 0x31, 0xC0, 0x64, 0x8B, 0x1D, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x89, 0xD8, 0x5B, 0xC3 };
        /*
        push ebx
        xor ebx,ebx
        xor eax,eax
        mov ebx,  fs : [0x00000030]
        mov eax, ebx
        pop ebx
         ret
         */
```

So I checked with ProcessHacker the PEB address and for x64 it is the same address I got from proc but for x86 I Got a difference of 0x1000 (4096).
I tested the two addresses (both x86 and x64) to get structure and all works fine.
My question is : How can I have a different address from my procedure in x86 with process hacker and the whole structure is readable ? (offsets are correct)

Comment: why so strange and not efficient asm code ? in wow64 process 2 peb exist so possible you mean defferent between 32 and 64 bit peb

Comment: @RbMm since I cannot write that 

#if defined(_WIN64)
    return (PPEB)__readgsqword(0x60);
#else
    return (PPEB)__readfsdword(0x30);
#endif

I made two basic procedures. Also idk that there are 2 PEB for WoW 64 and seems quite weird. There is only one.

Comment: *since I cannot write that* - why ? you of course can. but also - why so bad asm code ? and exist 2 PEB for WoW 64. not 1

Comment: @RbMm Don't blame OP for the strange asm code, he just copied it from the linked question.

Comment: @dialer - yes, but i think need how minimum understand such code before use. all what we need, if want use asm - `mov rax, gs:[60h]; ret` or `mov eax, fs:[30h]; ret` . for what use rbx(ebx) register and this manipulation - unclear. and of course we can use *intrinh.h* on windows and `__readfsdword`; `__readgsqword` so asm code not need at all

Comment: I don't write it because I work with C# @RbMm . This is why I cannot write that as simple it is in C++/C. This is why the code in ASM seems weird for you but it works very well with C#. Anyway it does not explain why there is a difference of 4KB with ProcessHacker or similar tools.

Comment: @Arsium - i already say you - exist **2** peb in wow64 process - 32 and 64 bit peb. and not use this asm. use mov rax, gs:[60h]; ret or mov eax, fs:[30h]; ret

Comment: @RbMm why should I not use asm above ? Just I try to understand.

Comment: @RbMm (I tested your asm code mov rax, gs:[60h]; ret or mov eax, fs:[30h]; ret and it works correctly) Also how and why are there two PEBs for X86 ? And how do I know which PEB I'm using ?

Comment: *why should I not use asm above ?* - why need use bad writed code. even if it only several instructions. *how and why are there two PEBs for X86*- not for x86 but for wow64 - 1 peb for 64 bit code and 1 for 32 bit. you got 32 bit peb this way