# Using MASM to generate Object files and link them with MSVC Object Files

Tags: c, linker, masm

I want to link an assembly file that contains just one function with an object file generated from. I would like to know how to create .obj files in MASM and I also need to know how to create such a function. Is this sufficient for a function that adds two ints together?

```
intadd PROC int1:DWORD int2:DWORD
mov eax, int1
mov ebx, int2
add eax, ebx
intadd ENDP
```

If I create and link the obj files, can I do

```
int x = intadd(1,1);
```

to receive 2?

To sum it up: I need to know how to create .obj files from MASM if they contain a Macro as above and how to call the macros from a HLL if my code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that a standard installation of Visual C++ will also install `ml.exe` and `ml64.exe`, both of which produce `.obj` files compatible with that version of Visual C++'s `link.exe`.

What you can do is, once you've assembled your assembly file with `ml /c asmfile.asm` into an `.obj` file, in your `.c` file, add the line:

```
extern int intadd(DWORD int1, DWORD int2);
```

Compile your `.c` code with `cl /c cfile.c`, then link both `.obj` files into the final executable with `link asmfile.obj cfile.obj /OUT:exefile.exe`.

Note that your assembly function is invalid, however, since once you're missing a `ret` statement - calling it will crash your program.

If you're seeking information on how to integrate assembly files into a Visual C++ project in Visual Studio, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751509/external-assembly-file-in-visual-studio) has some information.