# How to program x64 assembly with c++ in VS 2019?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly, x86-64

I am trying to get a very simple bit of x64 assembly to work using visual studio 2019, but it keeps giving me "fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals" I made sure masm was checked in build dependencies, and that is was in x64 mode; so, not sure what else to do since this is my very first prod into asm. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
extern "C" int someNumber();
int main() {
cout << "Number: " << someNumber() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

and

```
.code
someNumber proc
    mov rax, 222
    ret
someNumber endp
end
```

Comment: What's the rest of the linker error?  i.e., what is the mangled name of the symbol it is looking for?  You might just need to change `someNumber` in the assembly source to `_someNumber`.

Comment: 1>------ Build started: Project: assemb, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>assemb.cpp
1>assemb.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol someNumber referenced in function main
1>C:\Users\user\source\repos\assemb\x64\Debug\assemb.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "assemb.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: I tried adding the underscore and still a no go, and not sure what you meant by the mangled name of the symbol, but I will look that up and post asap--I am headed out at the moment. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: You need to include the .obj file created by the assembler when linking the CPP file.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: Did you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33757749/3512216? The order of the steps is important.

Comment: Normally all you have to do is check "masm" under "Project->Build Customizations..." for the project which contains the asm files; that tells MSBuild how to deal with `.asm` files (including linking, debugging, etc). It's possible that the `.asm` file is messed up in the `vcxproj`, in that case right click on the file -> Properties -> General -> Item Type: "Microsoft Macro Assembler". Using a custom build tool can also work, but it's unnecessary and VS won't understand it properly, so debugging won't work for example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom built tool (or step) for the assembly source file. Right click on the assembly source file name, then properties, ..., custom build tool ... .

For a debug build:

```
Command Line   ml64 /c /Zi /Fo$(OutDir)\someNumber.obj someNumber.asm
Outputs        $(OutDir)\someNumber.obj
```

For a release build, the same lines but without the /Zi

```
Command Line   ml64 /c /Fo$(OutDir)\someNumber.obj someNumber.asm
Outputs        $(OutDir)\someNumber.obj
```

In someNumber.asm, you need to declare the function as public:

```
        .code
        public someNumber
someNumber proc
        mov     rax, 222
        ret
someNumber endp
        end
```

VS2019 assembler ML64 defaults to "C" model, so there is no need to prefix names with "_".