# Microsoft Visual Studio unable to start program assemblyx86

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly

So I've been having this problem for a while it is usually a hit or miss. Sometimes I get the error, sometimes I don't.

I'm working on assembly x86 and everytime when I try to create a new project for .asm files, I get an error of the following

Unable to start program
...\Debug\Default*Projectname*.exe
The system cannot find the file specified

These are steps I use to make a file

1. Create project
2. Build MASM dependencies
3. Link Irvine library in additional dependencies

I'm able to build solution so that is kinda weird
Also, I'm trying to find a way that allow me to skip all the steps above and copy the default template

Comment: Do you mean MASM?  NASM is a different assembler that's not normally used with Irvine32 or Visual Studio.

Comment: Related: [Assembly programming - WinAsm vs Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52796300)

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right, I just checked it's MASM