# Can not build assembly code in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly

For some reason, I have to use some assembly code in my dll library project. My visual studio version is 2019.

I follow the settings as below to build assembly code

1. `Project` -> `Build customizations`, check `masm`
2. In the property of my assembly code file, set `Item Type` to `Microsoft Macro Assembler`

Then I build the project and got the following error.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\BuildCustomizations\masm.targets(70,5): error MSB3721: The command "ml64.exe /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"x64\Debug\my_assembly.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Tamy_assembly.asm" exited with code 1.

But if I go to my project directory and run `ml64.exe` with options in error message above, I can successfully build the assembly code.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\Hostx64\x64\ml64.exe" /c /nologo /Zi /Fo"x64\Debug\my_assembly.obj" /W3 /errorReport:prompt  /Tamy_assembly.asm
 Assembling: my_assembly.asm
```

After the manual build of `my_assembly.obj` from commandline, the build also succeed in visual studio IDE.

What's wrong with the `ml64.exe` invoked from visual studio IDE?

Comment: Possibly related: [Assembly programming - WinAsm vs Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52796300) or [external assembly file in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33751509) show what to click in VS.  I don't use VS, so maybe you already did exactly what those suggest.