# E0169 expected a declaration Visual Basic

Tags: assembly

Try to uninstall and reinstall visual Studios using assembly language was working two days ago but don't know what's causing the issue Irvine folder is on the C drive.
Don't know if the Syntax highlighting causing the issue but everything was working fine.

[Visual Studios screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoWKU.jpg)

Comment: Your IDE seems to think that is a C file.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate: [Assembly programming - WinAsm vs Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52796300) shows how to make a project where visual studio treats the file as asm, not C.  IDK why you mention Visual Basic; that's another language entirely.